# How to code efficiently an arbitrary number of loops in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

My problem is the following:

I have three types of numpy arrays. The first is an array we will call "y", this array is a 1D dimensional array of length y_n. The second type we will call "x", initially, these are 1D arrays of variable length i_n, where i belongs to {0,...,N}. However, at the moment where I need to operate "x", they are 2D with shape (y_n, x_i). The third type we can call "lamb" and it is simply a factor that I multiply to each "x" in its 2D form. The operation I perform is a sum of the "x". The resulting matrix I want is of shape (y_n, x_0, x_1, ...).

A short working code is the following:

```
y = [np.array([1., 2.])]
x = [np.array([1., 2., 3.]), np.array([4., 5.])]

lamb = [1., .5, 3., 4.]

for i, y_i in enumerate(y):
    first = np.einsum("j, -> j", y_i, lamb[i])
    
cross = []
for i, x_i in enumerate(x):
    cross.append(np.einsum("j, i, -> ji", y[0], x_i, lamb[1+i]))

p_y_x = np.zeros((2,3,2))
for k in range(2):
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(2):
            p_y_x[k,i,j] = cross[0][k,i] + cross[1][k,j]
```

This is already working and returns me the intended results. However:

1. I find this to be a non-elegant solution.
2. I don't know how would I scale this to an arbitrary number of "x" (or "y" for the matter.)

Is there any obvious way to do this better?

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid loops entirely, it is always better.  However, if you need to loop over indices of an array with arbitrary number of dimensions, you can use `np.ndindex`, for example:

```
p_y_x = np.zeros((2,3,2))
for indices in np.ndindex(p_y_x.shape):
    print(indices, p_y_x[indices])
```

The value of `indices` on each iteration will be a tuple.

You can if needed unpack the tuples of indices into individual variables (e.g. `k, i, j = indices`) or `for k,i,j in np.ndindex(p_y_x.shape):`, but then of course the number of dimensions is no longer arbitrary.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this might be the first step into a more elegant solution. I still wonder how to scale it into an arbitrary shape of p_y_x.